$f(n)=n^{100}$, $g(n)=2^{n/100}$, determine whether $f=O(g)$
I am reading Arora and Barak's book "Computational Complexity: A Modern Approach". I am doing EXERCISE 0.1.(b): $f(n) = n^{100}$, $g(n)=2^{n/100}$, determine whether $f=O(g)$.
Here's what I tried:
According to Definition 0.2: We say that $f=O(g)$ if there exists a constant $c$ such that $f(n) \leq c \cdot g(n)$ for every sufficiently large $n$. So we need to prove or disprove that there exists a constant $c$ such that $n^{100} \leq c \cdot 2^{n/100}$ for every sufficiently large $n$. I only know that the left side of the inequality is a polynomial of $n$, and the right side is an exponential function of $n$. The right side grows faster, so I guess the above description is true. But I don't know how to prove it. Any comments and answers are welcome.

If you want some exact values for $c$ and $N_0$, you can do $$\begin{align*}
n^{100} &\le c\cdot 2^{n/100} & \forall n \ge N_0 \\
100 \log n &\le \log c + \frac{n}{100} \log 2 & \forall n \ge N_0 \\
10000 \log n - n \log 2 &\le 100 \log c & \forall n \ge N_0
\end{align*} $$
Now lets take $h(x) = 10000 \log x - x \log 2$. We know $h'(x) = \frac{10000}{x} - \log 2$ and $h''(x) = -\frac{10000}{x^2}$. As $h''(x)$ is negative $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^+$, $h(x)$ must have a global maxima at $x_0$ where $h'(x_0) = 0$
$$\begin{split}
\frac{10000}{x_0} - \log 2 &= 0 \\
x_0 &= \frac{10000}{\log 2}
\end{split}$$
The maximum value of $h(x)$ is then $$ \begin{split}
h(x_0) &= 10000 \log \left( \frac{10000}{\log 2} \right) - \frac{10000}{\log 2} \log 2\\
 &= 10000 \left( \log \left( \frac{10000}{\log 2} \right) - 1\right) \\
 &= 10000 \log \left( \frac{10000}{e \log 2} \right) \\
100 \log c &\ge 10000 \log \left( \frac{10000}{e \log 2} \right) \\
\log c &\ge \log \left( \frac{10000}{e \log 2} \right)^{100}\\
c &\ge \left( \frac{10000}{e \log 2}\right)^{100}\\
c &= \left( \frac{10000}{e \log 2}\right)^{100} \text{  and  } N_0 = 0\\
\end{split}$$

Good answer, I hadn't considered using calculus to find a value for N0, and c.

Thank you very much! This is a good answer.

Take n = 2. Left side is 2^100 which is enormous compared to the right hand side. Which means you can forget about the constant c. The right hand side must grow enormously.
First how you might get an idea how large n needs to be: With n = 2, the left side is 2^100, so the right side must have an exponent >= 100, or n >= 10,000.
If n = 10,000 ≈ 2^(13 1/3), the left side is is about 2^1330 so the exponent on the right side must be 1,330 or n >= 133,000. If n = 133,000 ≈ 2^17, n^100 is about 2^1700 so you need n >= 170,000. That’s not growing a lot anymore. If n = 2^18 ≈ 262000 then n^100 is about 2^1800, so the exponent on the right hand side only needs to be 1800 and n <= 180,000.
That demonstrates that for n >= 180,000 the left hand side is much smaller than the right hand side. This is not a proof yet :-(
On the other hand you can also see that the numbers involved are enormous. A computer program running in n^100 nanoseconds will take several trillion years even in the case n=2, so the value of the statement is of limited value.

Thank you very much!

Not to give away the answer too quickly, but that definition is perfect for proving that f = O(g) in this case.
Basically as long as you can find some constant value for c, such that the equation $n^{100} \le c \cdot 2^{n/100}$ is true for "for every sufficiently large n", then the you have proven f = O(g).
"For every sufficiently large n" basically means, "Find if the equation is always true for all numbers $n \ge 1000$" or some other random positive number such that, it's always true as long as $n \ge SomeNumber$.
Because it's just "some constant value for c", you can actually just plug in $c = 1$, and work from there.
Now you're trying to prove for what values of n is $n^{100} \le 1 \cdot 2^{n/100}$ always true.
Now you can use logs to pull the exponents down, and re-arrange. However, you won't be able to use any simple algebra to solve for the exact value of n.
To truly use pure algebra to solve, you'd have to use the Lambert W function, which is usually not expected for these types of problems.
Now for some extra spoilers down here about the answer, so that I don't spoil it anymore than I have.

This is my re-arrange working: 


However, in my own Computer Science classes, I've just assumed something about how as n increases, log(n) / n as a function is always decreasing towards 0 after some value of n, but it's never increasing, and it never reaches 0. This is because log n = O(n), which can usually be assumed. Which proves that for all significantly large values of n, the re-arranged equation holds true. Which means that for all significantly large values of n, the original equation holds true too. That would be proof over, despite the fact that I never even found the value for n of which this is true.


(Assuming you can assume log n = O(n))

